# RuntimeError: Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll

Tags: python-3.x, dll, runtime-error, version

I understand that python v3.6.8 is not supported Python.Runtime.TypeOffset36. However, I have no idea what should I do..

Are there any solution even using v3.6.8?

**Error**

```
2022-12-15 22:07:55.381047: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
Failed to initialize pythonnet: System.NotSupportedException: Python ABI v3.6.8 is not supported: Searching for Python.Runtime.TypeOffset36, found TypeOffset,TypeOffset310,TypeOffset37,TypeOffset38,TypeOffset39.
場所 Python.Runtime.Native.ABI.Initialize(Version version)
場所 Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean initSigs)
場所 Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
場所 Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.InitExt()
場所 Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
場所 Python.Runtime.Native.ABI.Initialize(Version version)
場所 Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean initSigs)
場所 Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
場所 Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.InitExt()
場所 Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)Traceback (most recent call last):
***abbreviation***
 \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pythonnet\__init__.py", line 144, in load raise RuntimeError("Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll")
```

RuntimeError: Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll

Comment: Hi yuki, did you solve the issue?